# Implementing the effect of a button from a website

Tags: jquery, css, frontend, effect

I am trying to create an effect similar to one that I have seen on a website. The effect that I am talking about are the "View Details" buttons.

Here's the link: http://www.legworkstudio.com/

Can someone tell me how this is done, or if this is some plugin of JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 2):

It works animating a series of backgrounds.

```
https://legsite-production.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/desktop/sequences/detail-open/detail-open-00-aae01190cedcd36764097f5ff4765c27.png   
https://legsite-production.s3.amazonaws.com/assets/desktop/sequences/detail-open/detail-open-06-c56f3ce86232e1ca38660cf108a0f2e0.png   
etc
```

I've written a solution with jQuery: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GbS7Y/1/)

You can't use a solution with CSS `keyframes` because they don't support `background-image` if not in Google Chrome.
You should use a sprite, but then would be difficult make it responsive.

This is the example with @keyframes http://jsfiddle.net/DNXJX/ (Chrome only)